# WPF XAML shows some space between elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this XAML with few simple elements, that should go next to each other without any white space. However, some lines are displayed between them. 2 lines (thicker ones) are always displayed, and 2 more (very thin ones) - sometimes, when scrolling the entire work area horizontally or vertically. Latter, I believe, is due to the rendering options, but that could happen only if XAML elements didnt have its size set. In my case - every element has its size set. Why do those thicker and thinner lines appear and how can I remove them?

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                   Height="100" Width="10">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                   Height="100" Width="10">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                   Height="100" Width="30">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                   Height="10" Width="100">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                   Height="10" Width="100">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                   Height="30" Width="100">
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="100" Height="100"
                   StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green">
        </Rectangle>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Width="50" Height="50"
              Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="CanvasCornerLeftTop0_ClipRect" Rect="0,0 50,50">
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                     StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                     Height="100" Width="100">
            </Ellipse>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                       Height="100" Width="100"
                       Visibility="Collapsed">
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Width="40" Height="40"
              Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="CanvasCornerLeftTop1_ClipRect" Rect="0,0 40,40">
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                     StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                     Height="80" Width="80">
            </Ellipse>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                       Height="80" Width="80"
                       Visibility="Collapsed">
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Width="30" Height="30"
              Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="CanvasCornerLeftTop2_ClipRect" Rect="0,0 30,30">
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                     StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                     Height="60" Width="60">
            </Ellipse>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                       Height="60" Width="60"
                       Visibility="Collapsed">
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

*** UPDATE ***
Hadn't solved the problem with white lines, I just remade XAML elements and used PathFigure instead of Ellipses. Doesn't show any artefact lines now:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                Height="100" Width="10">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                Height="100" Width="10">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                Height="100" Width="30">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                Height="10" Width="100">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="White"
                Height="10" Width="100">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green"
                Height="30" Width="100">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="100" Height="100"
                StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="Green">
    </Rectangle>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Green">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="1,0">
                        <LineSegment Point="1,1"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="1,0" Size="1,1" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Fill="Green"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="White">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="1,0">
                        <LineSegment Point="1,1"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="1,0" Size="1,1" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Fill="White"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Green">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="1,0">
                        <LineSegment Point="1,1"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="1,0" Size="1,1" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Fill="Green"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: All that looks pretty straight forward (albeit you could cut the xaml in half by handling the dependency properties better and excluding default stuff) so I'd have to wonder if you don't have something somewhere specifying a small margin on TargetType Rectangle or something. Maybe a Style template being inherited or something?

Comment: No, nothing similar - and this XAML is the single page of a sample project, nothing else added, not as XAML nor as c# code

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the issue?

Comment: screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xb4tqeqndawfhvc/Clipboard02.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Ok I was visualizing something else without actually loading your xaml before seeing your screenshot, are you just trying to make a like rounded corner metro sign looking graphic? What's the result you're looking for exactly? We may be able to make this even simpler for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hadnt solved the problem with white lines, but remade my XAML structure instead. I need a rather complex set of figures. Imagine a complex road sign: few Tiles with corners like that, which can be either in corners, or along outer sides, or fully inside the road sign. So I need  - Corners: round/square outside, round/square inside + Sides: either 3 bars (green, white, green) od just 1 bar - white. Plus few more rectangles that I didnt write here - if Tiles make a group of Tiles inside one road sign.